# Android Room - Fails to order by date

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

My model fragment:

```
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "date")
@TypeConverters(TimestampConverter::class)
var date: Date? = null
```

My converter:

```
class TimestampConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return if (value == null) null else Date(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time
    }
}
```

My query:

```
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY date(date) DESC")
val all: LiveData<List<MyModel>>
```

Any ideas why Room is not sorting my data? Thanks.

Comment: if date is a timestamp in milliseconds in the table why not just do `ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: Hi! It works yeah. Create an answer please so I can accept it :). Any ideas why it does not work that way?

Comment: pretty sure `date()` looks for a date string and not a timestamp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make it only as `ORDER BY date DESC` in your Query.

Like

```
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC")
```